# How to connect multiple bluetooth A2DP/HFP-compatible phones to one bluetooth headset?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, mobile-phone, wireless-headset

I need to be able to use anytime - and anywhere! -  three mobile phones with a single bluetooth headset. Mobiles and headset supports A2DP and HFP bluetooth v2.0 profiles. I do not need to simultaneously use all at once but certainly I don't want to disconnect one in order to pair another.

According to the manual of the headset I'm using, it is able to make multipoint connection with only two devices. I have confirmed the manual specs as the headset ignores pairing requests from a third device while already paired with two.

I would prefer to keep the current headset if possible, as I'm quite confortable with it.

I tried searching for a portable intermediate device that would act as a proxy (ie. that device would A2DP/HFP pair a decently large number of phones, tablets, fm tuners, tv sets, pc - on one side -, then pair with the headset on the other side, so phones will all think they have paired with the headset proxy while the headset will think it's paired to ONE device) but I'm out of ideas of search keywords before finding any!

Comment: Does the headset support multipoint? If not, then there is not much you can do as you are limited by the headset capability.

Comment: I could not find a definition of multipoint, but according to product specs, it says "multipoint up to two devices". However I expect "multipoint" to be much more than just two but apparently that's what it means. Also I am hoping to find some kind of mixer/multiplexor portable device that I could use to hook all phones into then redistribute the audio and microphone to the headset, a device that would act as a proxy/bridge/hub/router/concentrator between all phones and the headset. Unfortunately I was not able to find such a product on google.

Comment: Which headset is it and which devices are to be connected?

Comment: Which devices are to be connected?

Answer (score 2):

It can work only as long as it's at least Bluetooth 2.1 headset but conflicts may still appear . I recommend BlueAnt z9i which can be connected upto 5 devices at once.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned not to suggest different headset!

Comment: That looks attractive but one of the phones has only v2.0 support even with latest available software update

Answer (score 0):

You wish to use the Motorola HX550 headset for three mobile phones.

However :

- The [manual](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/71063) says that only two phones can be paired simultaneously,
- Your experience is that this is correct.

Given these facts, there is no solution, since hacking the headset's firmware
is not an option.

Your only remaining options are to get a new headset that supports three paired devices,
or to exclude one of the three phones.

Comment: what I really want is a standalone bluetooth device that can act as a proxy between the phones/tablets/fm tuners/computer and the headset, but am unable to find such thing and stupid superuser rules forbids asking for product recommendation. three phones is just an example of anything more than two, could have been five or ten.

Comment: I have also tried to look for such a hardware product, without success. The headset market for more than 2 phones is apparently not that large. Some headsets can go with multipoint up to 5-8 pairs, although only one used at any one time.

Comment: @CostinGușă - If you cannot find it on the internet then it might not exist.  I have never heard of what you describe.  I wasn't even aware a device was able to pair to multiple devices I have always had to unpair my existing device to pair a new device.